# Invalid Id on visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I'm trying to insert a record but it is displaying this error: **Invalid id: Name of record** . can anyone check it?

### Controller

```
public class NightFlexList2Con {
 public string movieid{set; get;}
public string MovieAndWatchlist{set; get;}
public list<Nightflex__c>moviepopup{set;get;}

 public pagereference addmovie(){ 
    movieid = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
     
    moviepopup = [select id,name from nightflex__c limit 5]; 
    return null; 
} 
public List<SelectOption> getWatchlist() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    List<Watchlist__c>Watch_List = [Select Name from Watchlist__c];
    options.add(new SelectOption('','--Select a Watchlist-- '));   
    for(Watchlist__c WL: Watch_List)
    options.add(new SelectOption(WL.ID, WL.Name));    
    return options;
}

public PageReference doUpsert(){
    Movie_Watchlist__c objdlt = new Movie_Watchlist__c();
    objdlt.Movie__c = movieid;
    objdlt.Watchlist__c = MovieAndWatchlist;
    insert objdlt;
    return Move();
}
```

### VF page

```
 <h3>Movie Title: {!movieid}</h3>
<apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1" onchange="Select(this.value);">
                    <apex:SelectOptions value="{!Watchlist}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
<apex:commandbutton >
                <apex:commandButton value="Add Movie" action="{!doUpsert}">
                    </apex:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `movieid` contains a String value:

```
 <h3>Movie Title: {!movieid}</h3>
```

It's not clear from the supplied code whether `MovieAndWatchList` is a String or an Id value; it is typed as a String. You may wish to consider binding your `<apex:selectList>`'s value to a property in your controller to be clear; I don't know what your JavaScript method is doing.

You're using both variables to populate what appear to be relationship fields:

```
    objdlt.Movie__c = movieid;
    objdlt.Watchlist__c = MovieAndWatchlist;
    insert objdlt;
```

You must populate an Id value in a relationship field.

Comment: sorry i am new in salesforce. can you show me an example where I can insert or update records from multiple parents in the child object? cos that's what I am trying to do.

Comment: I would suggest completing the [Apex Basics and Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database) module on Trailhead, which covers this topic.